# How to capitalize section title in body document but not on table of contens

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titles

How do I capitalize section title in body document but not in table of contents. I use

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                  {\bfseries}}
```

to make it bold. But how do I capitalize it?
If I use

```
\section{\uppercase{Latar Belakang}}
```

the section title will be uppercase on both of body document and section title in table of contents.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What document class are you using? Why don't you use package `titlesec`?

Comment: Easy solution is to use \section[title]{Title}, albeit this requires more typing.  Try `\MakeLowercase` (standard LaTeX, also textcase).

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily disable `\uppercase` for the toc production.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand\uppercase[1]{#1}
\tableofcontents
}
\section{\uppercase{Latar Belakang}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to remove capitals then add them (correctly) to a title.

BTW, you really don't want to modify `\section` or `\@startsection` if you can avoid it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]% #1 = title (capitalized)
  {\section[\MakeLowercase{#1}]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mysection{Title}
\end{document}
```